# Automatic create Drop down List when opening Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

I want to create a dropdown list on Cell J1 from the "Brands" folder, inside of which there will be other subfolders like "Google", "Amazon", "Apple", "Microsoft".....

Display My Drive folder
[My Drive in Google Drive - BRANDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86eeu.jpg)

Display BRANDS folder
[Sub Folder in BRANDS folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt5uS.jpg)

I created 2 functions:

1. Function 1 the first function that stores subfolder names in a variable as an array.

---

---

```
function childFoldersList(parentFolder = 'BRANDS') {
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(parentFolder);
  var childFolders = parentFolder.next().getFolders();
  var amountFolder = 0;
  var eachFolder = [];
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    eachFolder[amountFolder] = childFolders.next().getName();
    amountFolder += 1;
  }
  return eachFolder;
}
```

---

---

2. Function 2 The second function is the OnOpen() function that after opening the Google Sheet, it will read the subfolders in the desired folder and create a drop down list in cell J1.

---

---

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var shTemplate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Template').activate();
  shTemplate.getRange('J1').clearDataValidations();
  shTemplate.getRange('J2').setValue('Creating DropDownList');
  var dataList=[];
  datalist = childFoldersList();
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J1');
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(datalist).build();
  rng.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

---

---

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhK79.jpg)

The result was 2 cases.
Case 1 when running **on the editor** The result came out that Cell J1 has a dropdown list As desired. and at cell J2 there is a message that says "Creating DropDownList"

[Case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TspdT.jpg)

Case 2: When **closing Google Sheets then open it again** As a result, cell J1 does not have a dropdown list. It's just a space, but at cell J2 it says "Creating DropDownList".

[Case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ow5S.jpg)

***I don't understand where the error occurred. Please help someone who knows how to solve this error.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try doing the same thing with an installable onOpen().  Name it someting different from onOpen()

Comment: Thank you very much Cooper. But I don't know why. Is that a bug in google app script?

Comment: No it's by design.  Simple triggers do not require authorization so they do not perform functions that do.